# GridView is trying to reach ArrayList data from out of bound

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview

I'm making `GridView` widget which loads images taken from `ArrayList` where is 40 of them. Those objects are loaded from memory to gridView perfectly fine but while I'm scrolling widget down, getViewAt method wants to load more of them which gets me to OutOfBounds `Exception`. However my method contains if statement, which should return null value in case of that, but probably there is some mistake made, here is my GetViewAt Method:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    if (position == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION ||
            cursor == null || !cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return null;
    }
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
        Bitmap img = resizeBitmapFitXY(250, 150, photos.get(position));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, img);
        return views;
}
```

Comment: can you share you logcat , or where is the `OutOfBounds Exception` in the `cursor` or in the `photos` list ?

Comment: it is on this line: Bitmap img = resizeBitmapFitXY(250, 150, photos.get(position));

Comment: i guess that your problem is here `photos.get(position)` take a look at the answer and let me know if this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quastion**

> where is the OutOfBounds Exception

**Answer**

> it is on this line: Bitmap img = resizeBitmapFitXY(250, 150, photos.get(position))

**Solution**

add this to the if statement

```
if (photos == null || photos.size() == 0 || position >= photos.size()){
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, but it's strange because I've already tried something like position > 39 which is basically the same as your condition. However, now I've got another strange situation, because GridView beside images is showing infinity amount of blank grid cells with "loading" text on it.. here is the pic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xox654wy2duz49y/2018-02-05%2014.19.19.jpg?dl=0